# javascript delete text on overflow

Tags: javascript

I have an html page I am using for a church service that uses window.SpeechRecognition to do closed captioning.   the words are in a div and the overflow off the top of the screen. but after awhile the program stops I think because the text gets to long.  how can I delete text that overflows off the top of the screen?

here is the code on code sandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kirch-vtihej?file=/index.html  as apparently the code snippet on stack overflow does not let you use the microphone.  anyway on the code sandbox just refresh it and click allow to use microphone.

```js
const badWords = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'grape'];

        window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;
        let finalTranscript = '';
        let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();

        recognition.interimResults = true;
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 10;
        recognition.continuous = true;

        recognition.onresult = (event) => {
            let interimTranscript = '';
            for (let i = event.resultIndex, len = event.results.length; i < len; i++) {
                let transcript = (event.results[i][0].transcript);
                const words = transcript.split(" ");
                const filteredWords = words.filter(word => !badWords.includes(word.toLowerCase()));
              
                if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                    finalTranscript += filteredWords.join(' ');
                } else {
                    interimTranscript += filteredWords.join(' ');
                }
            }

            document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = finalTranscript + '<i style="color:#FFFFFF;">' + interimTranscript + '</>';
            const myDiv = document.getElementById('container');
            myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
        recognition.start();
```

```html
<body style=" background-color: #000000;">
    <div style="height: 600px;
                     font-size: 100px;
                     color: white;
                     overflow:hidden;"
         id="container"/>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech recognition is not stopping to work because your text is overflowing, it's because it's programmed to stop on silence. So after longer silence is detected WebSpeech stops listening. You can try it by just saying "Hello" and waiting like 3 seconds in silence. Recording icon in your browser tab will disappear.

To combat the overflowing issue, I have better solution for you. Don't delete the text, just scroll to the bottom if new one is being added. You can do that by adding following to the bottom of: `recognition.onresult = (event) => {}` (This of course means, that you have to get rid of `overflow: hidden` in your div style)

```js
window.scrollTo({
    left: 0,
    top: document.body.scrollHeight, 
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

This will prevent the jumping you would have by deleting text and will be more pleasurable to read.

To combat the stopping issue, listen for `.end` event and restart the speech recognition as soon as it get emitted.